# Is there any way to use `workbench.action.quickOpenRecent` to open a new window?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I enjoyed the convenience of `workbench.action.quickOpenRecent`, but there's one downside, which is, unlike `workbench.action.openRecent`, the selected project can't be opened in a new window, is there any way to get around that?

Comment: @starball `workbench.action.quickOpenRecent` works more like Windows `alt+tab` on a Mac, the switch is instant, faster than swiping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by design. I raised an issue ticket asking about this, and a maintainer, [Tyler Leonhardt](https://github.com/TylerLeonhardt), [replied](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/199289#issuecomment-1834144901):

> Yeah so `workbench.action.quickOpenRecent` is one of these `quick` commands... which can also be confirmed via code [isQuickNavigate](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/cf1b0ce3d660a35a7060dbac9be7c045293ebaee/src/vs/workbench/browser/actions/windowActions.ts#L277) is set to `true`. This changes the behavior of how this quick pick operates which does have some quirks... for example, you don't see the input box, but the most important one relevant to this issue is that this is not intended to be used with modifier keys to alter the behavior. It's suppose to be a "quick" way of switching contexts. Having alternate behavior is intended to be used with the non-quick version of Open Recent.
>
> All that to say, this behavior is expected. The quick versions of these commands aren't intended to have alternate open behavior.

I suppose if you'd like this to be supported, you could [raise a feature-request issue ticket](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&projects=&template=feature_request.md). If you do, make sure to give context about that comment by Tyler. See also comments below.

#### Old, wrong answer

I'm leaving this here because I think it has educational value: that VS Code can be debugged, and that you can report issues and communicate with maintainers if you think a certain behavior is unexpected.

From my somewhat shallow reading of the relevant source code, Quick Open Recent is supposed to support holding <kbd>ctrl/cmd</kbd> to force opening in a new window and <kbd>alt/opt</kbd> to force reusing the same window. But when I debug VS Code 1.84 to follow what's going on, it behaves differently than Open Recent.

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/3481f35b91afff6c93d4888a528318d4f9f01a16/src/vs/workbench/browser/actions/windowActions.ts#L141

> ```js
> const pick = await quickInputService.pick(picks, {
>   ...
>   placeHolder: isMacintosh ? localize('openRecentPlaceholderMac', "Select to open (hold Cmd-key to force new window or Option-key for same window)") : localize('openRecentPlaceholder', "Select to open (hold Ctrl-key to force new window or Alt-key for same window)"),
>   ...
>   onKeyMods: mods => keyMods = mods,
>   quickNavigate: this.isQuickNavigate() ? { keybindings: keybindingService.lookupKeybindings(this.desc.id) } : undefined,
>   hideInput: this.isQuickNavigate(),
>   ...
> });
> if (pick) {
>   return hostService.openWindow([pick.openable], {
>       forceNewWindow: keyMods?.ctrlCmd,
>       forceReuseWindow: keyMods?.alt,
>       remoteAuthority: pick.remoteAuthority || null // local window if remoteAuthority is not set or can not be deducted from the openable
>   });
> }
> ```

When I debug Open Recent, pressing down and releasing <kbd>ctrl/cmd</kbd> does nothing, but pressing it down and then pressing <kbd>enter</kbd> down enters the `onKeyMods` callback with `{ "ctrlCmd": true, "alt": false }`.

When I debug Quick Open Recent, pressing down and releasing <kbd>ctrl/cmd</kbd> enters the `onKeyMods` callback with `{ "ctrlCmd": false, "alt": false }`, and the same for pressing it down and then pressing <kbd>enter</kbd>.

I suspect that this is unintended behavior and have raised a bug ticket: [Quick Open Recent does not support key modifiers to force new/reused window
#199289](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/199289).

Comment: If anyone reading this ends up raising an issue ticket like I suggested, please either comment here with the link to it, or notify me in it with "@starball5" and a link to this Stack Overflow post so I can update it.